# How to control the order in which CSV file headers are written by CsvHelper without using a class a mapping?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have the following method to write dynamic CSV file records:

```
 public byte[] BuildProductsFile(List<object> records)
    {
      var firstRow = records.FirstOrDefault();
      var columnHeaders = ((IDictionary<string, object>) firstRow).Keys.ToList();

      using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
      using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
      {
        using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter);
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);

      }
      return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
```

When I do WriteRecords, it changes header names to alphabetic order which I don't want since afterwards my rows correspond to incorrect headers. I can't use a class to specify header names because they will be different depending on different tables which user would like to get.

My question is can I write the header names in the correct sequence, which I can get from

```
var columnHeaders = ((IDictionary<string, object>) firstRow).Keys.ToList();
```

Alternatively, is there a way to disable alphabetical order header placing?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  You show your writing code but not how the `List<object> records` is created so your problem isn't necessarily easy to reproduce.

Comment: Also, what version of `CsvHelper` are you using?  In the current version (26.1.0) there is no `CsvWriter(streamWriter)` constructor.  The [constructor for CsvWriter](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/26.1.0/src/CsvHelper/CsvWriter.cs#L96) takes at least two arguments: `public CsvWriter(TextWriter writer, CsvConfiguration configuration)` or `public CsvWriter(TextWriter writer, CultureInfo culture, bool leaveOpen = false)`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the simple CSV sample from https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-dynamic-records, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/IjvZ9c.  The column order is not changed.  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].  See [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a version of `CsvHelper` between [10.0.0](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/releases/tag/10.0.0) and [12.0.0](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/releases/tag/12.0.0).  Between these two versions, `CsvWriter.WriteRecords()` would write `ExpandoObject` properties in alphabetical order.  Upgrade to a later version (or downgrade to an earlier version) to eliminate this behavior.

For confirmation, see the [change log](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log/):

> **10.0.0**
>
> **Features:**
>
> - Write ExpandoObject and IDynamicMetaObjectProvider object properties in ascending order to ensure order of property creation doesn't matter.
>
> ---
>
> **12.0.0**
>
> **Features**
>
> - Added config option for sorting dynamic object properties when writing. Defaults to property value set order.
>
> **Breaking Changes**
>
> - Added `IComparer<string> IWriterConfiguration.DynamicPropertySort`.
> - Added `IComparer<string> Configuration.DynamicPropertySort`.

See [When writing dynamic object order of property assignments is significant #1037](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1037) for a discussion of why this happened.

A demo of `CsvHelper` failing in version 11 can be found here: [demo #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ri6MRY).

A demo of `CsvHelper` working as desired in the most recent version, version 26, can be found here: [demo #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IjvZ9c).

And if you really need to write your CSV columns in an order specified by a sequence of strings, you can use `CsvConfiguration.DynamicPropertySort` mentioned above:

```
class OrderComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    // Note this comparer assumes that all strings to be compared are present in the incoming collection of strings, and will throw an exception if not.
    // If this is not desired, enhance as required.
    readonly Dictionary<string, int> orders;
    public OrderComparer(IEnumerable<string> orderedHeaders) => orders = orderedHeaders.Select((i, s) => (i, s)).ToDictionary(p => p.i, p => p.s);
    public int Compare(string x, string y) =>  orders[x] - orders[y];
}

public static  byte[] BuildProductsFile(List<object> records, IEnumerable<string> orderedHeaders) =>
    BuildProductsFile(records, new OrderComparer(orderedHeaders));

public static  byte[] BuildProductsFile(List<object> records, IComparer<string> dynamicPropertySort)
{
    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    {
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            DynamicPropertySort = dynamicPropertySort,
        };
        using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, config); 
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);

    }
    return memoryStream.ToArray();  
}
```

Demo of `DynamicPropertySort` here: [demo #3](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iDNVmw).